# Events handlers not invoked in Yammer embed

Tags: javascript, yammer

I have a Yammer feed embedded on a page. Recently I discovered that the events are not run.

I have the following event handler added:

```
yam.on('/embed/loggedIn', nd_yammer_login, '');
```

I also noticed some strange messages in the Javascript console:

```
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active yam-vendor-752d3d8ed7eb9318601b636b27167f79.js:30:469
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active yam-platform-feed-d48630d1b8ece576e0a38c9104838a5d.js:30:469
console.trace():
```

/Anders

Comment: what are we answering for?